# Not able to open a file in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I need to write an expect script to open a file and then search the contents for the file to see if it has the error code 1040.This is the code that I have written:

```
set f1 [open syslogs.txt r]
while {[gets $f1 line]!= -1} {
if {[regexp {.*1040.*} $line]} {
    puts "yes"
}
}
```

but when I try to run this script,it keeps showing

```
 couldn't open "syslogs.txt": no such file or directory
while executing
"open syslogs.txt r"


invoked from within
```

I changed the file permissions too.Can somebody please help me out with this..
When doing this from my local machine it works fine but when doing this by spawning a telnet session to a server it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure the file present in the directory where you running the script?  Tried with the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Check what the current directory is (see the `pwd` command) inside your script. If it isn't what you anticipate, that can thoroughly break things that use relative paths.

Comment: Yeah the file is created in the current directory

Comment: Do I have to add the full pathin the open filename statement?

Comment: after entering the absolute path,it stil shows me the same error

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

*open fileName access*

> Open the file for reading only; the file must already exist. This is
>   the default value if access is not specified.

the **r** access requires the file to exists and can't be created by the command itself.
Do you create it?
have you tried with an **a** or some other value of access?